# Why is this Class' object not serialized properly in different processes?

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, synchronization, deserialization

### Context

I made a Java application, and need to run two instances of that application, synchronizing some of their attributes via socket each time there's some change. To communicate those changes, `Serializable` objects are sent through a socket using ObjectStreams (input and output) using read/writeUTF() for an identifier, and read/writeObject() and flush(). The app is the exact same .jar, run twice with some changes like having different ports and ip (if necessary).

### Problem

I noticed that objects of some of my classes (e.g. `Notification`) were sent and received without any troubles, but objects from another class (`RegisteredUsers`) weren't sent (or received) properly. So I ran some tests to send objects between the two apps and found that the object is being sent and isn't null, it's attribute (a `HashMap<String,User>`) is also being sent and isn't null, but **is always empty**.
So I decided to scale it down to what the problem was exactly: I'm trying to write an object through a Stream, and read it in a different process of the same .jar, and with most classes it seems to work, but it doesn't with one.
There seems to be something I'm missing or don't understand about this serialization process, if the object is written and read during the execution of the same process it works, but not if this object is read on another instance of the same app. I even added a HashMap to Notification with the same creation process, but it still works, I really don't get it, what am I missing?

### Code

I have taken some code from the bigger app and trimmed it down to the basic problem if anyone wants to test it. To reproduce the errors, run Main1, which will create the two files with an object persisted in each one (one with a Notification object and the other with a RegisteredUsers object) and shows their information, then Main2, which reads them from the files and shows their information, and the problem should be printed. That being that reg3's HashMap is empty and thus neither of the Users are registered.

Main1

```
public class Main1 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regFile = "registry.txt";
        String notificationFile = "notification.txt";
        Persistence pers = new Persistence();
        
        RegisteredUsers reg1 = new RegisteredUsers();
        RegisteredUsers reg2 = new RegisteredUsers();
        
        reg1.register("Name1", "127.0.0.1");
        reg1.register("Name2", "127.0.0.1");
        
        try {
            pers.writeReg(reg1, regFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error writing registry.");
        }
        try {
            reg2 = pers.readReg(regFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading registry.");
        }
        System.out.println("Original registry: ");
        System.out.println(reg1.isRegistered("Name1") + " " + reg1.isRegistered("Name2"));
        System.out.println("Registry read from file: ");
        System.out.println(reg2.isRegistered("Name1") + " " + reg2.isRegistered("Name2"));
        
        Notification noti1 = new Notification("Name", "127.0.0.1");
        Notification noti2 = new Notification(); //not necesary but it's the way it's done in the bigger app.
        try {
            pers.writeNotif(noti1, notificationFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error writing notification.");
        }
        try {
            noti2 = pers.readNotif(notificationFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading notification.");
        }
        System.out.println("Original notification: ");
        System.out.println(noti1.getAttributes().get(0) + " " + noti1.getAttributes().get(1));
        System.out.println(noti1.getMap());
        System.out.println("Notification read from file: ");
        System.out.println(noti2.getAttributes().get(0) + " " + noti2.getAttributes().get(1));
        System.out.println(noti2.getMap());
    }
}
```

Main2

```
public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regFile = "registry.txt";
        String notificationFile = "notification.txt";
        Persistence pers = new Persistence();
        RegisteredUsers reg3 = new RegisteredUsers();

        try {
            reg3 = pers.readReg(regFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading registry.");
        }
        if (reg3 == null) {
            System.out.println("reg3 is null");
        }
        if (reg3.getMap() == null)
            System.out.println("reg3 has a null map");
        if (reg3.getMap().isEmpty())
            System.out.println("reg3 has an empty map");
        
        System.out.println("Registry read from file on another process: ");
        System.out.println(reg3.isRegistered("Name1") + " " + reg3.isRegistered("Name2"));
        
        Notification noti3 = new Notification(); //not necesary but it's the way it's done in the bigger app.
        try {
            noti3 = pers.readNotif(notificationFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading notification.");
        }
        System.out.println("Notification read from file on another process: ");
        System.out.println(noti3.getAttributes().get(0) + " " + noti3.getAttributes().get(1));
        System.out.println(noti3.getMap());
    }
}
```

A Class to persist the objects in the files:

```
public class Persistence {
    public void writeReg(RegisteredUsers regus, String file) throws IOException {
        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);) {
                oos.writeObject(regus);
                oos.flush();
            }
    }
    
    public RegisteredUsers readReg(String file) throws IOException {
        RegisteredUsers regus = null;
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);) {
                regus = (RegisteredUsers) ois.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong class.");
        }
        return regus;
    }
    
    public void writeNotif(Notification regus, String file) throws IOException {
        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);) {
                oos.writeObject(regus);
                oos.flush();
            }
    }
    
    public Notification readNotif(String file) throws IOException {
        Notification notif = null;
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);) {
                notif = (Notification) ois.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong class.");
        }
        return notif;
    }
}
```

RegisteredUsers

```
public class RegisteredUsers implements Serializable {
    private static HashMap<String, User> users;
    
    public RegisteredUsers() {
        users = new HashMap<String, User>();
    }
    
    public HashMap<String, User> getMap() {
        return users;   
    }
    
    public boolean isRegistered(String name) {
        User us = users.get(name);
        return us != null;
    }
    
    public void register(String name, String ip) {
        users.put(name, new User(name, ip, false));
    }
}
```

Notification

```
public class Notification implements Serializable {
    private ArrayList<String> attributes;
    private HashMap<String, User> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    public Notification() {
    }
    
    public Notification(String name, String ip) {
        attributes = new ArrayList<String>();
        attributes.add(0, name);
        attributes.add(1, ip);
        map.put(ip, new User(name, ip, false));
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public HashMap<String, User> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
}
```

User

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String ip;
    private boolean connection_state;

    public User(String name, String ip, boolean connection_state) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.connection_state = connection_state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java `static` fields are implicitly `transient`, and transient fields are not serialized.

If you modify the `RegisterdUsers` to

```java
public class RegisteredUsers implements Serializable {
    private HashMap<String, User> users; // static modifier is removed
    ...
}
```

The serialization will work.

Comment: ... and serialization works for Main1, since the `users` field is shared between the two objects `reg1` and `reg2`

Comment: I knew the reason was something silly and I was just not seeing it, thank you SO much for the answer. The variable wasn't even supposed to be static at all, don't even know when I added it.